# Run jQuery after Angular is done loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

> I'm writing some code to slightly modify an existing website.
>
> The existing website is built with Angular. My code is using jQuery, but I can use any JavaScript.
>
> However, I cannot change the existing website. I cannot change the existing Angular scripts. I can change my one external script file that is a src on the site. My code is running after the Angular scripts and jQuery scripts have been loaded.

*How can I have my jQuery code run after Angular is done rendering the DOM?*

`$(document).ready()` fires to early.

> I've never used Angular, but reading online, it looks like it should emit a `$viewContentLoading` event, however I have not been able to capture this event in my script.

Thanks,

Comment: i did't understand your question.  Can you show me your code?

Comment: @user256103 I do not have any code. I'm trying to find a code sample that will allow jQuery code run after Angular is done rendering the DOM. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. You need to wait for the DOM to load before attempting to run any jQuery!

The easy- and unsafe- way to do it is to use `$timeout` in angualrjs. [See the doc here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).

```
$timeout(function() {
    //your jQuery code here
}, 50);
```

This is telling angualrJs to wait 50 milliseconds then execute whatever is inside the function. 50 milliseconds should be enough time- but you might have to increase it if your page loads slow.

**There is a better way!**

You should look into [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to avoid using jQuery.

Comment: I considered a timeout, but that seems really messy.

Comment: I considered a timeout, but that seems really messy.

Again, I cannot add to the existing Angular files. 

I tries to add a directive, but it is not working. I've tried several variations, none seem to work... Any chance you could help make this work? Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/6gdfx29x/2/

Comment: Also, I'm trying to get the timeout to work, but I cannot even make this work:
http://jsfiddle.net/xavsrmL7/

Answer (score -1):

As of date:

**Sample of Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
declare const $: any;
declare const JQuery: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-jquery',
  templateUrl: './jquery.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jquery.component.scss']
})
export class JQueryComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // Right way, view fully ready here
    console.log($); 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Wrong, view not always fully ready here
    console.log(JQuery); 
  }

}
```

**Explanation**

1. Download the [jquery](https://jquery.com/) min css & js files to your public assets dir **src/assets**
2. Add these CSS & JS JQuery files via the styles & scripts arrays respectively in the **angular.json** file.
3. To test if jquery / $ is being added properly, you should not encounter any build error due to these changes, else resolve them all most likely due to missing required assets.
4. Add #5 line below just after the last import of any component or service to access the $.
5. `declare const JQuery:any;`
6. Add the line below just after the last import of any component or service to access the JQuery.

---

> However it is important to be aware of the [angular component
> lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)
>
> As most will try accessing `$ / JQuery` within the ngOnInit method
> most times which is called once and is best for initialization not
> ready state events.

---

7. **In components where you have to access `$ / Jquery`, you have to `implement` the `AfterViewInit` and `override/implement` the  `ngAfterViewInit()` which is invoked immediately after Angular has completed the initialization of a *component's view*. It is invoked only once when the view is instantiated / ready to render.**

Therefore you can consider writing any block of code that has to wait for `$(document).ready()` in the `ngAfterViewInit` method to ensure to implement `AfterViewInit`.